# take/restore filesystem snapshots instantly and without reboot

Tags: windows-7, snapshot

I keep my workspace on a separate NTFS drive. Is it possible to instantly take snapshots (using COW) and restore them instantly too? The free space on the same filesystem is supposed to be used for that, like in System Restore. But the windows frontend for System restore seems to be not very powerful.

upd: Looks like there was a tab "Shadow copies" in drive properties in older windows version, that did exactly what I neeed, but now it's missing.

Comment: The full Shadow Copy feature-set is only available on server versions of Windows. You could play with the command line tools though.

Comment: enwiki: On Windows 8 persistent shadow copies are no longer available.

Comment: Does it mean that on Windows 7 they're possible with vshadow tool?